# What languages support writing things once?

Tags: language-design

As an example we expect that we can define *sum* on entities of type **OrderedCollection[Monoid]**, where **Monoid** is a trait/interface with an associative operation with a zero. Then we shouldn't need to cut and paste the code for *sum* to use it. But types can be monoids in more than one way: e.g. positive integers with + and 0 or with * and 1. I can't work out a nice way to handle this.

Comment: There was an answer (which has disappeared?) supporting Scala's system. It is however very ugly, particularly because the general parameter that can be defaulted comes at the end, while it naturally belongs close to the thing it is modifying. I had this thought. Suppose we allow rich text. In particular suppose we allow subscripts (smaller font displaced down). It doesn't seem so ugly for this to be called with a default value when no subscript is provided. It could maybe use method .subscript a la .apply. Is this the compelling reason for going from plain text to rich text for language fmt?

Comment: The question title should be edited as it doesn't reflect the actual question. Should be something like "how to implement abstract monoids in a language and avoid ambiguities?"

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has a nice trick to handle the case for many monoids using `newtype` language feature:

http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/01/haskell-monoids-and-their-uses.html (read from "The same type can give rise to a monoid in different ways.")

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Monoid.html#3 (the official documentation on library additive and multiplicative monoids for numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to be explicit about which operation you wish to use? I don't see any sane way of avoiding this.

In Clojure I'd just use a higher-order function:

```
(defn sum-with [op]
  (fn [coll] 
    (reduce op coll)))
```

Then you could do:

```
(def sum1 (sum-with +))
(sum1 [1 2 3 4])
=> 10

(def sum2 (sum-with *))
(sum2 [1 2 3 4])
=> 24
```